# GetBreadcrumbNavigationLinks doesn't return all Links

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-1.7

Our application recently have the following issues, even though we haven't made any changes to the source code.

So we have a `CustomNavigationContoller` with an `ActionResult Breadcrumb` that uses
`SiteConfiguration.NavigationProvider.GetBreadcrumbNavigationLinks` to get the NavigationLinks.

Let say you try to open the following url /english/company/event.html, the NavigationLinks should contain 3 links with the following urls:

- /english
- /english/company/
- /english/company/event

Everything is working as expected for all of the old pages that we have created. But when I try to create a new page in the /english/company directory and render it, it doesn't return the last link item. In my case: /english/company/{name of the new page}.

I am not sure whether the information is taken from LINK_INFO table in the database, but the link do exist there.

I tried to decompile `Sdl.Web.Common.dll`, where the `GetBreadcrumbNavigationLinks` method is, but didn't get a lot of information from it.

Have anyone of you faced similar issues? Do you have any idea, what could be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tung Do , please can you provide the Tridion version ,is it SDL Web 8.1.1 or SDL Web 8.5 and I assume you are using DXA1.7, is your webapp running on .NET or Java , when you accessed the new page did you find any details on the logs.

Comment: Not 8.5, so I guess under 8.0 version. Yes it DXA 1.7 and .dll is .NET. It doesn't seem anything special appear on the log, when i try to open the page.

Comment: Did you republish the _Navigation Page *after* publishing the new Page?  You can request `/navigation.json` to see if the new Page is incorporated in the Navigation Model.

Comment: Yes, the new Page is incorporated in the Navigation.json file.

Comment: Please show the fragment of the Navigation JSON for this new Page.

Comment: Does the title of the new Page start with a 3-digit number (a so-called *sequence prefix*) ?

Comment: BTW: instead of decompiling, you can get the sources from GitHub and compile/debug the DXA Framework code yourself.

Comment: ```"Url":"/corporate/company/events/Gartner_IT_xpo","Type":"StructureGroup","Items":[{"$id":"612","Title":"Gartner IT Symposium I Xpo 2019 Barcelona","Url":"/corporate/company/events/Gartner_IT_xpo/default","Type":"Page","Items":[],"PublishedDate":"2019-07-24T13:16:14.277","Visible":false,"Id":"tcm:389-185828-64"}```

Comment: I will download and try to compile/debug the framework. Let me know if you see something strange in the navigation.json

Comment: The SitemapItem for the Page has `Visible: false`. Does your Page title start with 3 digits?